# Why in specific range same image is duplicating in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to develop android application which can load images from the url in to RecyclerView With the help of Picasso library. But the problem comes that after some sequence "in my case after every 6 image" same image is duplicating in recyclerview. I'm added some code

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

in my adapter but this is not working for me.
Below is my currant adapter code please help me to findout the solution for this.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private Img[] data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Img[] data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Img user = data[position];

        final String imageStr = user.getImgurl();
        String taKey = loadTaluka();
        final String id = user.getImgId().toString();

        if (user.getTaluka().equals(taKey)) {
            float date = Float.parseFloat(user.getDateTime());
            float lastDayDate = Float.parseFloat(dispDate()) - 1;
            if (date >= lastDayDate) {
                Picasso.with(holder.myImg.getContext()).load(imageStr).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_1).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(holder.myImg, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(holder.myImg.getContext()).load(imageStr).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_1).into(holder.myImg);
                    }
                });



            }
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoadImg.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url", imageStr);
                    intent.putExtra("id", id);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


/*
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }*/
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userTitle;
        TextView age;
        TextView country;
        TextView url;
        public ImageView myImg;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImg);
        }
    }


    //Extras


    private String loadTaluka() {
        SharedPreferences sf = context.getSharedPreferences("Taluka", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sf.getString("taluka", "a");
    }

    //Image Viewholder Adapter End
    private String dispDate() {
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        String dayFinal = day.format(c);

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        String monthFinal = month.format(c);

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        String yearFinal = year.format(c);

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat hour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
        String hourFinal = hour.format(c);

        String finalDate = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(dayFinal) + Integer.parseInt(monthFinal) + Integer.parseInt(yearFinal)) + "." + hourFinal;

        return finalDate;
    }


}

  -Thankyou.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of Recycler views RAM Management, the recycler view try to load cards from the cache and because of your recycler view's cache, the items loads incorrectly.
for preventing this you must add an `else` to your `if` like this:

```
if (date >= lastDayDate)
{
    //Do Your Code
}
else
{
    //The Default Item View Settings Here...
}
```